# Region wise Author Post management

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

- Created a plugin to create Regions as custom Taxonomy.
- Users will be mapped to Regions using user meta. (from edit user page)
- posts are displaying based on the assigned region.
- But the posts count showing differently.

single file plugin is as given below.

configuration:

1. install
2. create regions
3. edit user and assign region
4. create posts as admin & user - with and without regions
5. check user post listing

   ```
   /*
   Plugin Name: Region Author Mapping
   Plugin URI: 
   Description: Simple plugin limit authors to post based on regions.
   Version: 1.0
   Author: 
   Author URI: 
   */


   /* Disallow direct access to the plugin file */
   defined('ABSPATH') || die('Sorry, but you cannot access this page directly.');

   if (!class_exists('region_author')){
       class region_author{

   public  $txtPostType  = 'post';
   public  $txtDomainReg = 'author_regions';
   public  $taxRegions   = 'regions';

   /**
    * class constractor
    * @author Ohad Raz
    * @since 0.1
    */
   public function __construct(){

       $this->hooks();

       if (is_admin()){
           $this->adminHooks();                
       }
   }

   /**
    * hooks add all action and filter hooks
    * @since 0.6
    * @return void
    */
   public function hooks(){

       // save user field
       add_action( 'personal_options_update', array( $this,'save_extra_user_profile_fields' ));
       add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', array( $this,'save_extra_user_profile_fields' ));

       // add user field
       add_action( 'show_user_profile', array( $this,'extra_user_profile_fields' ));
       add_action( 'edit_user_profile', array( $this,'extra_user_profile_fields' ));

       //admin hack for region mapping
       add_filter('parse_query', array( $this,'convert_id_to_term_in_query' ));
       add_action('restrict_manage_posts', array( $this,'filter_post_type_by_taxonomy' ));

       //region taxonomy CREATION
       add_filter('init',array($this, 'create_regions_hierarchical_taxonomy'));
   }

   /**
    * hooks add all action and filter hooks for admin side
    * 
    * @since 0.7
    * @return void
    */
   public function adminHooks(){
       //remove quick and bulk edit
       global $pagenow;
       if ('edit.php' == $pagenow)
           add_action( 'admin_head-edit.php', array(&$this,'remove_quick_edit')); //add_action('admin_print_styles',array(&$this,'remove_quick_edit'));

       //add region metabox
       add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add_regions_meta_box' ) );
   }

   /**
    * remove_quick_edit
    * @author Ohad   Raz
    * @since 0.1
    * @return void
    */
   public function remove_quick_edit() {
       global $current_user, $pagenow;
       if ($pagenow != 'edit.php')
           return;
       $user_regions = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, '_author_regions', true);
       if (!empty($user_regions) && count($user_regions) > 0) {
       ?>
           <script type="text/javascript">         
               jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
                   $('.cat-checklist.regions-checklist').prev().prev().hide();
                   $('.cat-checklist.regions-checklist').hide();
               });    
           </script>
       <?php
       }
   //            global $current_user;
   //            $user_regions = get_user_meta($current_user->ID,         '_author_regions', true);
   //            if (!empty($user_regions) && count($user_regions) > 0) {
   //                echo '<style>.cat-checklist.regions-checklist{display: none!important;}</style>';
   //            }
   }

   /**
    * Adds the meta box container
    * @author Ohad Raz
    * @since 0.1
    */
   public function add_regions_meta_box(){

       global $current_user;
       get_currentuserinfo();
       $reg_tax = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, '_author_regions', true);
       if (!empty($reg_tax) && count($reg_tax) > 0){
           //remove default metabox
           remove_meta_box('regionsdiv', 'post', 'side');
           //add user specific regions
           add_meta_box( 
                'author_regions'
               ,__( 'Regions',$this->txtDomainReg )
               ,array( &$this, 'render_region_meta_box_content' )
               ,$this->txtPostType 
               ,'side'
               ,'low'
           );
       }
   }

   /**
    * Render Meta Box content
    * @author Ohad   Raz
    * @since 0.1
    * @return Void
    */
   public function render_region_meta_box_content(){
       global $current_user, $post;
       $postRegionTerms = array();
       get_currentuserinfo();
       $regions = get_user_meta($current_user->ID,'_author_regions',true);
       $regions = (array)$regions;

       // Use nonce for verification
       wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'author_regions_noncename' );
       if (!empty($regions) && count($regions) > 0){
           if (count($regions) == 1){
               $c = get_term( $regions[0], $this->taxRegions);

               echo __('this will be posted in: <strong>',$this->txtDomainReg) . $c->name .__('</strong> Region',$this->txtDomainReg);
               echo '<input name="tax_input[regions][]" type="hidden" value="'.$c->term_id.'">';
           }else{
               echo '<span style="color: #f00;">'.__('Make Sure you select only the regions you want: <strong>',$this->txtDomainReg).'</span><br />';
               $options = get_option('author_regions_option');
               //GETTING SAVED REGIONS OF A POST
               $screen = get_current_screen();
               if ($screen->parent_base == 'edit') {
                   $postRegions = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $this->taxRegions);
                   if($postRegions){
                       foreach ($postRegions as $key => $region) {
                           $postRegionTerms[] = $region->term_id;
                       }
                   }
               }
               foreach($regions as $region ){
                   $c = get_term( $region, $this->taxRegions);
                   $checked = (in_array($region, $postRegionTerms))? ' checked="checked"' : '';
                   echo '<label><input name="tax_input[regions][]" type="checkbox"'.$checked.' value="'.$c->term_id.'"> '.$c->name .'</label><br />';
               }
           }
       }
   }

   /**
    * This will generate the regions field on the users profile
    * @author Ohad   Raz
    * @since 0.1
    * @param  (object) $user 
    * @return void
    */
    public function extra_user_profile_fields( $user ){ 
       //only admin can see and save the regions
       if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) { return false; }
       global $current_user;
       get_currentuserinfo();
       if ($current_user->ID == $user->ID) { return false; }
       $select = wp_dropdown_categories(array(
                      'orderby' => 'name',
                      'show_count' => 0,
                      'hierarchical' => 1,
                      'hide_empty' => 0,
                      'echo' => 0,
                      'taxonomy' => $this->taxRegions,
                      'name' => 'author_regions[]'));
       $saved = get_user_meta($user->ID, '_author_regions', true );
       foreach((array)$saved as $c){
           $select = str_replace('value="'.$c.'"','value="'.$c.'" selected="selected"',$select);
       }
       $select = str_replace('<select','<select multiple="multiple"',$select);
       echo '<h3>'.__('Author Regions', 'author_regions').'</h3>
       <table class="form-table">
           <tr>
               <th><label for="author_regions">'.__('Regions',$this->txtDomainReg).'</label></th>
               <td>
                   '.$select.'
                   <br />
               <span class="description">'.__('Select a region to limit an author to post just in that region (use Crtl to select more then one).',$this->txtDomainReg).'</span>
               </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <th><label for="author_regions_clear">'.__('Clear Regions',$this->txtDomainReg).'</label></th>
               <td>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="author_regions_clear" value="1" />
                   <br />
               <span class="description">'.__('Check if you want to clear the region limitation for this user.',$this->txtDomainReg).'</span>
               </td>
           </tr>
       </table>';
   }

   /**
    * This will save region field on the users profile
    * @author Ohad   Raz
    * @since 0.1
    * @param  (int) $user_id 
    * @return VOID
    */
   public function save_extra_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
       //only admin can see and save the regions
       if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options') ) { return false; }

       //AUTHOR REGION SETTINGS
       update_user_meta( $user_id, '_author_regions', $_POST['author_regions'] );

       if (isset($_POST['author_regions_clear']) && $_POST['author_regions_clear'] == 1)
           delete_user_meta( $user_id, '_author_regions' );
   }

   /**
    * CREATE REGIONS TAXONOMY
    */
   public function create_regions_hierarchical_taxonomy() {

       $labels = array(
           'name' => _x('Regions', 'taxonomy general name'),
           'singular_name' => _x('Region', 'taxonomy singular name'),
           'search_items' => __('Search Regions'),
           'all_items' => __('All Regions'),
           'parent_item' => __('Parent Region'),
           'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Region:'),
           'edit_item' => __('Edit Region'),
           'update_item' => __('Update Region'),
           'add_new_item' => __('Add New Region'),
           'new_item_name' => __('New Region Name'),
           'menu_name' => __('Regions'),
       );

       // Now register the taxonomy
       register_taxonomy($this->taxRegions, array($this->txtPostType), array(
           'hierarchical' => true,
           'labels' => $labels,
           'show_ui' => true,
           'show_admin_column' => true,
           'query_var' => true,
           'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'region'),
       ));
   }

   /**
    * Display a custom taxonomy dropdown in admin
    * @author Mike Hemberger
    */
   public function filter_post_type_by_taxonomy() {
       global $typenow;
       if ($typenow == $this->txtPostType) {
           $selected = isset($_GET[$this->taxRegions]) ? $_GET[$this->taxRegions] : '';
           $info_taxonomy = get_taxonomy($this->taxRegions);
           //TO EXCLUDE UNWANTED TAXONOMY TERMS
           $user_regions = array();
           global $current_user;
           $user_regions = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, '_author_regions', true);
           $tax_dropdown = array(
               'show_option_all' => __("All {$info_taxonomy->label}"),
               'taxonomy' => $this->taxRegions,
               'name' => $this->taxRegions,
               'orderby' => 'name',
               'selected' => $selected,
               'include' =>  $user_regions,
               'hide_empty' => false,
           );
           // CREATING THE ADMIN FILTER DROPDOWNS
           wp_dropdown_categories($tax_dropdown);
       }
   }

   /**
    * Filter posts by taxonomy in admin
    * @author  Mike Hemberger
    */
   public function convert_id_to_term_in_query($query) {
       global $pagenow, $typenow, $current_user;
       $q_vars = &$query->query_vars;
       $user_regions = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, '_author_regions', true);
       $selected_tax = ((isset($_GET[$this->taxRegions])) && ($_GET[$this->taxRegions] !=0)) ? $_GET[$this->taxRegions] : '';//DROPDOWN FILTER SELECT
       $author_tax = isset($_GET['author']) ? $_GET['author'] : '';
       $tax_slug = array();
       if (($pagenow == 'edit.php') && ($typenow == $this->txtPostType) ) {
           if (!$user_regions) { //ADMIN
               $term = get_term_by('id', $selected_tax, $this->taxRegions);
               $tax_slug[] = $term->slug;
           } else { //OTHER USERS
               $regTaxArray = ($selected_tax)? (explode(',', $selected_tax)) : $user_regions;
               foreach ($regTaxArray as $key => $regTax) {
                   $term = get_term_by('id', $regTax, $this->taxRegions);
                   $tax_slug[] = $term->slug;
               }
           }
           //TO UNSET AUTHOR PARAMETER FOR POST LISTING OF - "Mine"
           if($author_tax){
               unset($q_vars['author']);
               $q_vars['author__in'] = explode(',', $author_tax);
           }
       }
       $q_vars[$this->taxRegions] = implode(',', $tax_slug);            
       $selected_tax = isset($_GET[$this->taxRegions]) ? $_GET[$this->taxRegions] : '';
           }
       }//end class
   }//end if
   //initiate the class on admin pages only
   if (is_admin()){
       $ac = new region_author();
   }
   ```

The real problem is I am setting the author__in parameter of the query_vars from pre_get_posts filter. Afterwards, it doesn't resets from the main query.

tried all the wp functions for reseting query.

It almost killed me. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: `But the posts count showing differently`, where? What part of the code is not working?

Comment: i don't have control over the posts count here, that is my problem. query change is happening within the function 'convert_id_to_term_in_query'

Comment: The real problem is I am setting the author__in parameter of the query_vars from pre_get_posts filter. Afterwards, it doesn't resets from the main query.